# How to get different columns with JSON (PHP)?

Tags: php, json

I am very very new at PHP and I don't even know JSON. Also, I couldn't know how to express it in the question. My question is;

I need to make a JSON data with PHP with the data from database. So what my expected output is like;

```
{ "canFireAPICalls": true, "ads": { "servers": [ { "type": "OpenX", "apiAddress": "http://openx.openvideoads.org/openx/www/delivery/fc.php", } ], "schedule": [ { "zone": "5", "position": "pre-roll" }, { "zone": "33", "width": 450, "height": 50, "startTime": "00:00:05", "duration": "15" } ], } }
```

What I wrote in PHP is;

```
while ($doZones->fetch() && $row = $doZones->toArray()) {
    $row_array['zone'] = $row['zoneid'];
    $row_array['position'] = $row['delivery'];

    if($row['delivery'] == 0 || $row['delivery'] == 1 || $row['delivery'] == 4 ){
        $row_array['width'] = $row['width'];
        $row_array['height'] = $row['height'];
    }


    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$resultJSON .=json_encode($return_arr);
```

And my output is

```
{ "canFireAPICalls": true, "ads": { "servers": [ { "type": "OpenX", "apiAddress": "http://openx.openvideoads.org/openx/www/delivery/fc.php", } ], "schedule":[{"zone":"3","position":"6"},{"zone":"2","position":"6"},{"zone":"4","position":"6"},{"zone":"5","position":"6"},{"zone":"6","position":"1","width":"468","height":"60"},{"zone":"7","position":"6","width":"468","height":"60"},{"zone":"8","position":"0","width":"120","height":"600"},{"zone":"9","position":"7","width":"120","height":"600"},{"zone":"10","position":"0","width":"120","height":"600"},{"zone":"11","position":"0","width":"728","height":"90"},{"zone":"12","position":"0","width":"120","height":"90"},{"zone":"13","position":"1","width":"468","height":"60"},{"zone":"14","position":"3","width":"468","height":"60"},{"zone":"15","position":"1","width":"560","height":"40"},{"zone":"16","position":"4","width":"468","height":"60"},{"zone":"17","position":"6","width":"468","height":"60"},{"zone":"18","position":"6","width":"468","height":"60"},{"zone":"19","position":"7","width":"468","height":"60"}] } }
```

If you noticed, even there shouldn't be width and height, there is. I only want the width and height when $row['delivery'] is 0,1 or 4. But, once it finds a value 0,1 or 4, then even if the next row is not 0,1 or 4, it prints width and height. Is there a way to fix this? I don't know any JSON and just started with PHP. Right now, I don't care about the missing tags like duration or writing pre-roll. I will take care of them after I fix this.

Comment: this has nothing to do with JSON, make sure you're getting the right data into the `$return_arr`; i.e use `print_r($return_arr);` and see what's in it

Comment: you can use `json_encode($array)` and `json_decode($value)` in build php function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your php. You don't reset the values of your array `$row_array`, so the first time the condition is true, the values of height and width are kept in the array.

You can fix it this way :

```
while ($doZones->fetch() && $row = $doZones->toArray()) {
    $row_array['zone'] = $row['zoneid'];
    $row_array['position'] = $row['delivery'];

    if($row['delivery'] == 0 || $row['delivery'] == 1 || $row['delivery'] == 4 ){
        $row_array['width'] = $row['width'];
        $row_array['height'] = $row['height'];
    }


    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    // Add this line to reset the array and reset width / height
    $row_array = array();
}

$resultJSON .=json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't know I should do that. I'll accept your answer in 50 seconds